# Create Virtual Fields on the Fly in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to duplicate the answer to this question but in CakePHP 3: [Search distance between 2 points CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448763/search-distance-between-2-points-cakephp)

How do I create virtual fields on the fly for CakePHP 3?

And here's my custom finder, which of course doesn't work because of the bad virtual field creation:

```
protected function findByDistance($lat, $long, $distance)
{
    $distanceValue = $this->calcDistance($lat, $long, $this->_properties['latitude'], $this->_properties['longitude']);
    $this->virtualFields['distance'] = $distanceValue;
    return $query->where(['distance <=' => $distance]);
}
```

Comment: see if [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462718/cakephp-query-closest-latitude-longitude-from-database/38522403#38522403) answer can help

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.